# log4j Daily and size based appender with new log file every restart

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

Im trying to create log4j appender which:

-Creates new log file every day

-Creates new log file every application restart

-Creates new log file every 500mb

-Saves old log files to zip

I tried different configurations, below is last one. But this one also does not work. Is it even possible to do what i need?

```
<appender name="default" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="log.log" />
    <param name ="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyyMMdd" />


    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="activeFileName" value="log.log" />
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="log_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.%i.zip"/>
      <param name="minIndex" value="1"/>
      <param name="maxIndex" value="10"/>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500 MB" />
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>

    <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>

    <layout class="mycustomlayout">

    </layout>

  </appender>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you might need custom Appender implementation based on `DailyRollingFileAppender` but adding the "zipping old stuff" to `rollOver()` method.

Comment: I know I had to copy and modify the code for `DailyRollingFileAppender` in order to create `CompressedDailyRollingFileAppender`. Also, I would suggest using gzip instead of zip (log_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.%i.gz) because then you would be able to use vim,zcat,zgrep and more to view your logs without decompressing them first

Comment: It actually works if i set it just to cut log every 500mb and every restart. I thought switching RollingFileAppender to DailyRollingFileAppender will do the work...